# Indexing Not working after installed Smile Elastic search extension Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch

I have installed Smile Elasticsearch extension successfully.But i am not able to reindex catalogsearch_fulltext indexer.
I have installed elasticsearch successfully on my local server.

Please check below screenshots and let me know proper solution.
Please help!!!

Magento Version: 2.1.6
Module Version: 2.2.3
Elastic Engine: 1.7.2

[image]

[image]

Please check my configuration from below screenshot,
http://nimb.ws/Cu7aEX

Your help would be appreciated.!!!

Comment: Can you please provide smileelastic search version, Magento version and elastic search engine installed in your system?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question.

Comment: @AshishViradiya  Have you find any solution? Can you please let me know actual issue.Thanks!

Comment: There is default issue with smileelastic search with magento 2, i am finding the solution. you can use mirasvit its batter then the smile elastic https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/elastic-search-ultimate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sunny Please downgrade your Elasticsearch version from 6.5.4 to 2.x as 6.5.4 does not support in Magento 2.1. Please refer below links for more details.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to install phonetic plugin on elastic search server.
Run this command to install the same :

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

Comment: I have already installed this plugin.

Comment: The error shows that plugin is not installed. You can check if plugin is installed by running: 'sudo bin/plugin list' command

Comment: Thanks for your answer but phonetic plugin already installed on my server.Please check this screenshot.  http://nimb.ws/X2mEkq

Answer (score 0):

May be because of missing  plugins of elasticsearch
( analysis-phonetic and analysis-icu )

solution:

-enter elasticsearch server
-find default location for elasticsearch(whereis elasticsearch)
usually at  /usr/share/elasticsearch
Then .....

- cd /usr/share/elasticsearch (or your location where elasticsearch exist)
- bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
- bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
- sudo service elasticsearch restart
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade